# Solving $f'(x) = f(f(x))$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Is there any solution to the differential equation $f'(x) = f(f(x))$?

I couldn't find any information on this kind of DE

Comment: $f(x)=0$ is a solution.

Comment: There's a solution of the form $f(x)=cx^\alpha$. Can you find $c$ and $\alpha$?

Comment: @Berci not if $\alpha$ is a real number.

Comment: If a nonzero solution exists with a fixed point $f(x^*)=x^*$ (with $x^*\neq 0$) then you can find it with a series solution $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(x-x^*)^kf^{(k)}(x^*)}{k!}$. You can compute $f'(x^*)=f(f(x^*))=f(x^*)=x^*$, $f''(x^*)=f'(f(x^*))f'(x^*)=f'(x^*)^2 = (x^*)^2$, and so on.